# $.ajax is not a function when being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

for some reason when I run npm start and I hit the browser, I am getting this stack trace with this error.

TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

```
at getLocationFromIp (G:\Github\Expressjs\nodetest1\routes\index.js:13:7)
at G:\Github\Expressjs\nodetest1\routes\index.js:24:14
```

Would someone be able to tell me why? Here is my code.  Thanks!

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var externalip = require('external-ip');
var $ = require('jquery');

getLocationFromIp = function() {
    $.ajax({
       url:"freegeoip.net/json/",
       type: "GET",
       data: null,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(){console.log("success!")}
     });
 }

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ip = getLocationFromIp();
    res.render('index', { 'ip' : "hi"});
});
```

Comment: Try adding the code inside of $(document).ready(function(){}) function

Comment: @Dale — What `document`?

Comment: The problem probably lies with a-sync loading of Jquery via the require function. Is there a way to fire getLocationFromIp function AFTER Jquery script loads? That it likelly to solve your problem.

Comment: @Elvanos — Since when was `require` async?

Comment: Hmm... is there a way to make jquery fire after the require loads? if that is the issue

Comment: @PatrickGuan — require is not async

Comment: Don't use jQuery with NodeJS

Answer (score 6):

See [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery):

> For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.

```
var externalip = require('external-ip');

require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var $ = require("jquery")(window);

     function getLocationFromIp() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "freegeoip.net/json/",
            type: "GET",
            data: null,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() {
                console.log("success!")
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("error", arguments[2])
            }
        });
    }
    var ip = getLocationFromIp();
    console.log(ip);
});
```

---

You'd probably be better off using an HTTP library designed to work with Node from the outset, such such as [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Comment: that means i would have to run npm install jsdom as well? and how would this fire? onload?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to install jsdom in order to use that. `onload` makes no sense in this context, nothing is loading. You'd just to set up jQuery before you started the server. As I said, you'd be better off using a different library to make HTTP requests, it would be much simpler.

Comment: If its the case that its missing a document, then would one solution be to just simply move this ajax call to the client side instead?

Comment: You'd probably run straight into the same origin policy.

Comment: I got this working in TypeScript too. I posted the gist here: https://gist.github.com/ctaggart/87fea160bea50c11a36954bd4dc865c5

Comment: .env() is deprecated since v10. The new method is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48561379/5958842).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request  - This package has been deprecated
Author message: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery to just make a http request, you can probably use the http or request node module to do that instead.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var externalip = require('external-ip');
var http    = require('http');

getLocationFromIp = function(done) {
  var options = {
    host: "freegeoip.net",
    port: 80,
    path: "/json"
  };

  var request = http.get(options, function(response) {
    var result = "";
    var responseCode = response.statusCode;

    response.on('data', function(data) {
      result += data;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
      if(responseCode >= 400)
        return done(result, null);
      else
        return done(false, JSON.parse(result));
    });
  });

  request.on("error", function(error){
    return done("Error handling error", null);
  });

  request.end();
}

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ip = getLocationFromIp(function(error, ip){
      res.render('index', { 'ip' : "hi"});
    });
});
```