# jsdom.env not working on node.js C9

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

So I've been working with Node.js on C9 recently and ran into this problem in a javascript file:

```
jsdom.env("", function(err, window) {
TypeError: jsdom.env is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var $;
jsdom.env("", function(err, window) {
console.log("what");
if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
}

$ = require("jquery")(window);

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
  });
});
```

I updated all my dependencies as well as Node itself but still get this problem. Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: How are you getting a reference to `jsdom`?

Comment: Updated I had it in my ide but forgot to add to the website.

Comment: “As of v10, jsdom has a new API (documented [here](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#basic-usage)).”

Comment: Thanks a lot brah

Comment: @Michael Gee... I think you forgot to accept my answer... It would be highly appreciated if you do it...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Was looking for the solution all over the web. It turned out that jsdom has updated some of their features since v10. So, I wanted to use jQuery in the Node.js end of an express app.
For those who are just looking for answers about how to include `jQuery` in `Node`, I would like to mention that you'll need to install jsdom  using `npm install jsdom` and `jQuery` using `npm install jquery`. Then:

For `jQuery` to work in `Node`, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in `Node`, one can be mocked by `jsdom` as below:

```js
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

.env() is deprecated since v10. Hope this helps you or anyone who has been facing these types of issues.

Comment: I am using your code but got the error: `$.getJson is not a function`

Comment: You're running that on client side jaavscript or at Node's end ?

Comment: I am running it at node end

Comment: Firstly, install jquery and jsdom from using npm install. Then, add these lines in the file you're trying to use jquery selector in.
For instance, I used a $.each. I just included these lines and then did it like below:
$.each(errors, function (ind,error) {
            res.send(error.msg);
            console.log(error.msg);
  });

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, .env() is deprecated. 
Use the following:

```
const { window } = new JSDOM(``, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
const myLibrary = fs.readFileSync("../../whatever.js", { encoding: "utf-8" });

const scriptEl = window.document.createElement("script");
scriptEl.textContent = myLibrary;
window.document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
```

In regard to the answer above, and from the jsdom docs:
**Don't stuff jsdom globals onto the Node global**

> A common antipattern we see when people use jsdom is copying globals
>   from a jsdom window onto the Node.js global, and then trying to run
>   the code---intended for a browser---inside Node.js. This is very bad
>   and you should not do it. It runs code intended for the web browser in
>   some kind of hybrid franken-environment polluted with a ton of globals
>   that don't make sense there, and loses all benefits of isolating your
>   code into a jsdom window.

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/wiki/Don%27t-stuff-jsdom-globals-onto-the-Node-global

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: npm install jquery

Step 2: npm install jsdom

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    //add dummy function to test jquery in Node
    function fn1( value ){ console.log( "fn1 says " + value );}  
function fn2( value ) {console.log( "fn2 says " + value ); return false;}
    var jsdom = require('jsdom');
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
    const { window } = new JSDOM();
    const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
    //comment out the line below it create problem
    //global.document = document;
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
    var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
    callbacks.add(fn1);
    callbacks.fire("foo!");
    callbacks.add( fn2 ); 
    callbacks.fire( "fool!" );
```